# How to pass a parameter to WCF RIA Service query through URI

Tags: c#, wcf, uri, ria, domainservices

I have a custom WCF RIA Service query that accepts one parameter. I can access the method via URI by calling:

```
/WCF_RIA_ServiceData.svc/GetJobDataByEmployee
```

but because my query is dependant upon the parameter being passed, nothing is returned.
I have tried to pass the parameter(int) multiple ways:

```
/WCF_RIA_ServiceData.svc/GetJobDataByEmployee(1)
/WCF_RIA_ServiceData.svc/GetJobDataByEmployee/1
/WCF_RIA_ServiceData.svc/1/GetJobDataByEmployee/
/WCF_RIA_ServiceData.svc/GetJobDataByEmployee?EmployeeID=1/
/WCF_RIA_ServiceData.svc/GetJobDataByEmployee?1/
```

All of which fail. Can someone please let me know how to call the method with a parameter? Thank you for any info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.

```
/WCF_RIA_ServiceData.svc/GetJobDataByEmployee?EmployeeID=1/
```

is the correct way to call it, but you have to specify that it has side-effects by adding this line before your method in the WCF RIA Service.

```
[Query(HasSideEffects = true)]
```

I don't quite understand why this is required, because in my case the code doesn't actually cause any side-effects. If anyone has any information on why this is required please let me know.